# Specific Autocomplete types in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I've been trying to use google maps api to auto fill a location field (using javascript)
I used the establishment filtering as I only wanted specific places. But I realized that establishments was still too broad.
Is it possible to narrow it down even more ? I wanted to narrow it down to only hospitals, clinics, etc.
[This link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) Says that only geocode, establishment and regions are possible in autocomplete.

I wanted to use more specific types like the ones found in [this link](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types) 
I wasn't able to find any resource which explains how to use those types for auto complete.
Can someone help me out with this ?

PS : I'm using maps api v3

Comment: Try defining the type as suggested on the developer page

Comment: I did, it didnt work. Google didn't return anything at all

Comment: please try once the google map place api for the place suggestion it has a working code in the example at the documentation only

Answer (score 1):

If you want only specific places like hospitals or pharmacy etc, you can use PlacesService to find the exact locations available. Pre-fetch these places based on location and show them as autocomplete suggestion. Hope  this helps.